# How i can do one switch with link by role, ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I 'm new to ROR . I'm trying to make a switch with conditions. Someone can help me with the correct code

```
<%= link_to "Profile", (user = User.find(1)
case user.role
when "A"
redirect_to(url)
when "B"
redirect_to(url)
when "C"
redirect_to(url)
else
redirect_to(url)
end)%></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code.

```
<% user = User.find(1) %>
<% case user.role %>
<% when "A" %>
  <%= link_to "Profile", "YOUR URL" %>
<% when "B" %>
  <%= link_to "Profile", "YOUR URL" %>
<% when "C" %>
  <%= link_to "Profile", "YOUR URL" %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Profile", "YOUR URL" %>
<% end %>
```

One, more thing it's not good to write this code into view file. rails provide helper method to write your business logic for view file.

Answer (score 0):

In user helper

```
 def role_link(user)
  case user.role
    when 'A'
      url = 'redirect_url'
    when 'B'
      url = 'redirect_url'
    when 'C' 
      url = 'redirect_url'
  else
    url = 'redirect_url'
  end
  url
end
```

In view file

```
  <%= link_to 'profile', role_link(User.find(1) %>
```

Comment: Thanks! This run, but no works.
It always takes the 'else' option.
I'm check the database and it's good.

That I can do?

Comment: Can you tell me  what user.role is returning ?

Comment: Yes, user.role have a char in the table, but this always return the "else" option. Something is wrong, because, i try with if-elsif and equal.

def role_link(user)
   user = User.find(1)
   if user.rol == 'A'
    url = 'http://www.facebook.com'
   elsif user.rol == 'C'
    url = 'http://www.google.com'
   elsif user.rol == 'E'
    url = 'http://www.hattrick.com'
   else
     url = 'http://stackoverflow.com'
   end
 end

And ever... Stackoverflow

Comment: I'm define this metod in application_helper, it's correct?

Comment: It is readable and maintainable if we keep create helper method to related controller. for an instance for UsersController => UserHelper. Application helper can also be used and available in view.